# Out of memory using awk

Tags: csv, awk, memory-leaks

I am using awk to process a CSV data file. There are three fields in my data file, say file a.txt. I want awk to read a field from another file b.txt, then write the line from my a.txt if the first column matches the expression that was read b.txt. I have found the following to do what I want.

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=","} { while(getline l < "b.txt") PATS[l] }ok=0;{for (p in PATS) if ($1 ~ p) ok=1}; ok {print $0}' < a.txt
```

However, I get a huge memory leak and the program exits with a memory error. a.txt is about 41000 lines. I would be grateful if anyone could point me to the memory hog and/or suggest an alternative solution.

Comment: how big is b.txt? Are you aware you are reading b.txt once for each line of a.txt?

Comment: Read http://awk.info/?tip/getline and post the actual error message you are getting.

Comment: Hi @glennjackman, unless OP did `close("f2")`, wouldn't it read complete `b.txt` for first line of `a.txt only? All the subsequent runs would do nothing since `EOF` would reach during first run itself, or am I missing something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `getline` to validate two files like this isn't a great idea and could very well be the root cause of your issue. There are many caveats with `getline` function and even though it is an excellent tool, it is often misused.

I would recommend to use `awk` built in variables `NR` and `FNR` to scan through your `b.txt` file and store it in an array. Once you have loaded the array, you can check for `$1` from `a.txt` if it matches the key of your array.

Something like:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{PATS[$0]++;next}$1 in PATS' b.txt a.txt
```

Notice how I have placed two files after the awk command. What this does is, until `NR` and `FNR` are same (will only be same for first file, after first file is completed, `FNR` will get reset to 1) we create an array called `PATS` and use entire line as the key. `next` prevents the second `awk` statement from running. Once `b.txt` is completed we move to `a.txt` file and look for `$1`'s presence in your array. If it is true, it will evaluate to `1` and print that line. If `$1` is not present in your array, it will evaluate to false and not print the line.

The above command will look for an exact match though. I see you've used match operator `~` which means partial match as well. If that's what you want then you can do:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{PATS[$0]++;next}{for(p in PATS) if($1~p) print $0}' b.txt a.txt
```

If this doesn't work for you, I would recommend posting some sample data from both files.

Comment: Hi jaypal, this was great. It seem to work well and it's very fast, as well as very elegant. I had used this very method in the past, but with much smaller files, and in those cases I did not notice any problem. Thank you very much for the explanation as well.

Answer (score 1):

This does what you want if your shell is bash or ksh (or maybe zsh)

```
grep -f <(sed 's/^/^/; s/$/,/' b.txt) a.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Glenn. This also seem to work just as well, but I am less familiar with sed, and I would feel less comfortable in modifying this in case I needed.